# Проблема с манифестом android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: android, android-studio

При попытки протестировать приложение на устройстве, все ломается и выдает ошибку:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dell.lteneighboringcellinfo, PID: 22337
java.lang.SecurityException: getAllCellInfo: Neither user 10099 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.
```

Код манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Код MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.dell.lteneighboringcellinfo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

public void onClickStop(View v) {
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
}
```

Код сервиса, в котором я работаю с параметрами мобильной связи:

```
package com.example.dell.lteneighboringcellinfo;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.CellInfo;
import android.telephony.CellInfoLte;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

public class MyService extends Service {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

private TelephonyManager tm;
private CellInfoLte cellInfoLte;
PhoneStateListener MyListener;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
    someTask();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
}

public void someTask() {
    MyListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength sStrength) {
            List<CellInfo> cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
            for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {
                if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                    cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte) cellInfo;
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CI: " +        cellInfoLte.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    };

    tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

}
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Android API 22+ ? Тогда нужен запрос на данное разрешение, ибо он относится к группе опасных, Dangerous permissions

Comment: Да, 23 API. Как сделать такой запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
```

Comment: Да, помогло. Спасибо.